add line between rows
Please solve my problem
I want to add a black line between the lines,
But no line is added,
firstImage:

I want lines like the first picture:

import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Table,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  TableContainer,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  Paper,
  TablePagination,
  Chip,
  Rating,
  TextField,
  InputAdornment,
} from "@mui/material";
import NoData from "../noData/NoData";
import TableActions from "./TableActions";
import { Search } from "@mui/icons-material";

const TableComp = ({
  columns,
  data,
  actions,
  onActionClick,
  rowsPerPageOptions = [10, 25, 100],
}) => {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const [selectedRowId, setSelectedRowId] = useState(null);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(rowsPerPageOptions[0]);

  const handleMenuClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
    setSelectedRowId(null);
  };

  const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
    setPage(newPage);
  };

  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
    setRowsPerPage(+event.target.value);
    setPage(0);
  };

  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");

  const filteredData = data.filter((row) =>
    columns.some((column) => {
      const value = row[column.id];
      if (value === null || value === undefined) return false;
      return value.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase());
    })
  );

  return (
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <TextField
        fullWidth
        variant="outlined"
        placeholder="بحث..."
        value={searchQuery}
        onChange={(e) => setSearchQuery(e.target.value)}
        sx={{
          m: 2,
          maxWidth: "320px",
          "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
            borderRadius: "8px",
          },
        }}
        InputProps={{
          startAdornment: (
            <InputAdornment position="start">
              <Search />
            </InputAdornment>
          ),
        }}
      />

      <Table stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table" sx={{ minWidth: 650 }}>
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            {columns.map((column) => (
              <TableCell
                key={column.id}
                align={column.align || "left"}
                sx={{
                  width: "160px",
                  color: "#19213D !important", // Change header font color to blue
                  fontWeight: 700,
                  fontSize: "14px !important",
                }}
              >
                {column.label}
              </TableCell>
            ))}
            <TableCell
              align="center"
              sx={{
                width: "150px",
                color: "#19213D !important", // Change header font color to blue
                fontWeight: 700,
                fontSize: "14px !important",
              }}
            >
              الإجراءات
            </TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {filteredData.length === 0 ? (
            <TableRow>
              <TableCell colSpan={columns.length + 1} align="center">
                <NoData text="لا توجد بيانات لعرضها" />
              </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ) : (
            filteredData
              .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
              .map((row) => (
                <TableRow
                  key={row.id}
                  sx={{
                    "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 },
                    borderBottom: "2px solid red", // إضافة خط أحمر بين الصفوف
                  }}
                >
                  {columns.map((column) => (
                    <TableCell key={column.id} align={column.align || "left"}>
                      {column.id === "level" ? (
                        <Chip
                          label={row[column.id]}
                          style={{
                            backgroundColor:
                              row.level === "A"
                                ? "#f44336"
                                : row.level === "B"
                                ? "#ff9800"
                                : row.level === "C"
                                ? "#4caf50"
                                : "inherit",
                            color: "#fff",
                            width: "3rem",
                          }}
                        />
                      ) : column.id === "rate" ? ( // تحقق إذا كان العمود هو "rate"
                        <Rating
                          name={`rating-${row.id}`}
                          value={row.rate} // قيمة الـ rating هنا
                          readOnly // اجعلها للعرض فقط، إذا كنت لا تريد تعديلها
                        />
                      ) : row[column.id] !== undefined ? (
                        row[column.id]
                      ) : (
                        "-"
                      )}
                    </TableCell>
                  ))}
                  <TableActions
                    actions={actions}
                    row={row}
                    onActionClick={onActionClick}
                    anchorEl={anchorEl}
                    handleMenuClose={handleMenuClose}
                    setAnchorEl={setAnchorEl}
                    selectedRowId={selectedRowId}
                    setSelectedRowId={setSelectedRowId}
                  />
                </TableRow>
              ))
          )}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
      <TablePagination
        rowsPerPageOptions={rowsPerPageOptions}
        component="div"
        count={filteredData.length}
        rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
        page={page}
        onPageChange={handleChangePage}
        onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        labelRowsPerPage="عدد الصفوف في الصفحة"
        labelDisplayedRows={({ from, to, count }) =>
          `${from}–${to} من ${count !== -1 ? count : `أكثر من ${to}`}`
        }
        nextIconButtonText="التالي"
        backIconButtonText="السابق"
      />
    </TableContainer>
  );
};

export default TableComp;


Can check if the lines are appearing after adding more rows?
